# Eclipse UTF8 configuração

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8

*Alguém sabe como configura o eclipse para utf8?*

Procurei em configurações mas mesmo assim não consegui

Answer (score 6):

**Caminho no Eclipse:** Window > Preferences > Digite "Encoding".

Troque todos os tópicas que achar necessário para UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferences > Workspace:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edita onde tem "Text file encoding". Lembrando que no linux por padrão vem UTF-8, mas no windows vem um ISO. É sempre bom alinhar o enconding entre desenvolvedores desses diferentes SOs pra evitar aqueles erros horríveis de encoding no repositório do projeto.

Comment: Obrigada, funcionou